# Printing intermediate results in Scheme

Tags: scheme

I want to make a program that makes a conversion simulating a for loop, for example:

```
orig value   converted
1            2.2
2            4.4
...
199          437.8
```

So far, what I have done is the following:

```
(define (conv ini)
  (if (> ini 199)
      0
      (begin(
             (display (* ini 2.2))
             (newline)
             (conv (+ ini 1))))))
```

but when I want to run it I got the following error:

```
arity mismatch;
 the expected number of arguments does not match the given number
  expected: 1
  given: 2
  arguments...:
```

I see that my recursion call is fine, so I cannot get it which one is the problem.

Comment: Or, you could use a `cond` and forget about `begin`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax of `begin` is `(begin form ...)` not `(begin (form ...))`: your function should be

```
(define (conv ini)
  (if (> ini 199)
      0
      (begin
        (display (* ini 2.2))
        (newline)
        (conv (+ ini 1)))))
```

(Or, if you are enamoured of a syntax like that, you could define

```
(define-syntax beguine
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(_ (form ...))
     (begin form ...)]))
```

and then `(beguine (...))` will work.)

Comment: Silly to use `beguine` instead of just loosing the excess parentheses :-o

Answer (score 1):

```
  ...
  (begin(
         (display (* ini 2.2))
         ...))))
```

In your code you actually try to execute `(OP ...)`, where *`OP`* is the value of `(display ...)`, which for sure is not a function.

So I doubt a lot your output is the output of what you pasted in your question.